# Different name servers for different subdomains of a subdomain

Tags: dns, bind

We need to have a different name server for multiple subdomains of a subdomain. For example,

```
john.users.example.com
jack.users.example.com
```

I tried adding NS for subdomains `*.users.example.com` but it doesn't work. I tried following combinations (the domain is hosted on name.com)

Following works, but only for `users.example.com` it uses the new name server

```
users.example.com NS new.nameserver.com
```

Following works too

```
*.example.com   NS new.nameserver.com
```

But this does not work

```
*.users.example.com   NS new.nameserver.com
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong?